# Joomla and Calibre

Tags: joomla-3.7

Good Day,
I could use some help and advice on getting Calibre to run within Joomla,
Or, a solution that would offer me something equal to Calibre.

CBiscuit

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Calibre, the open source e-book management  software, then the closest Joomla extension is probably [OS Book Library](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/living/education-a-culture/booklibrary-basic).

If not, then you'll probably need to be more specific.

Comment: I solved my own problem, by creating my own version of an online private library.

Comment: @CBiscuit which library was it, perhaps others could use the same solution.